# Need help for flutter layout

Tags: flutter

Stack Overflow community!
I'm working on a UI layout and I'm trying to achieve a specific arrangement where my WidgetRightSideBar is located directly above my WidgetBottomFooterBar. How to do it?

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKoGp.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8fjP.png)

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0idZ.png)

This my current code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: MySingleChildScrollKeyboard(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Consumer<NotifierProviderFloorPlan>(
                builder: (context, data, child) {
                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          context.watch<NotifierProviderInfo>().posInfo.isHideBar
                              ? Container()
                              : Expanded(
                                  flex: 3,
                                  child: Container(),
                                ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: context.watch<NotifierProviderInfo>().posInfo.isHideBar
                                ? 33
                                : context.watch<NotifierProviderChannelState>().isMenuOpen
                                    ? 28
                                    : 30,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: MyTheme.paddingLeftRightTop(context),
                                    child: ThemeCategoryTab(
                                      listObject: data.listModelOutletTableArea,
                                      onChanged: (var value, int index) {
                                        if (value != null) {
                                          var index = data.listModelOutletTableArea.indexOf(value);
                                          data.onTapFloorSelection(index);
                                        }
                                      },
                                      currentValue: data.listModelOutletTableArea.isNotEmpty ? data.listModelOutletTableArea[data.indexFloor] : null,
                                      text: (int index) {
                                        return data.listModelOutletTableArea[index].name;
                                      },
                                      rowLength: 8,
                                      columnLength: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 20,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: MyTheme.padding(context),
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        (data.listModelOutletTableArea.isEmpty)
                                            ? Center(
                                                child: ThemeTitle(
                                                  HelperTranslate(context).translate.floor_is_empty.capitalize(),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            : FloorWidget(
                                                isLoginFromTenderFloorPlan: widget.isLoginFromTenderFloorPlan ?? false,
                                              ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: WidgetBottomFooterBar,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          WidgetRightSideBar()
                        ],
                      ),
                      WidgetLeftSideBar(),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

expected WidgetRightSideBar is located directly above my WidgetBottomFooterBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the footer out of the inner column, because if the column wrapped with row, the footer will stay in the column and not expand to the right side.

So you need to:

1. Wrap your row layout with column.
2. Move your footer to the end of outer column (newly created column).

Like illustration below:

[image]
(left: your current layout, right: modification)

My simple workaround on dartpad:
[image]

And this is your final code:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: MySingleChildScrollKeyboard(
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Consumer<NotifierProviderFloorPlan>(
            builder: (context, data, child) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  Column( // <- wrap the layout with column
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 20,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            context.watch<NotifierProviderInfo>().posInfo.isHideBar
                                ? Container()
                                : Expanded(
                                    flex: 3,
                                    child: Container(),
                                  ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: context.watch<NotifierProviderInfo>().posInfo.isHideBar
                                  ? 33
                                  : context.watch<NotifierProviderChannelState>().isMenuOpen
                                      ? 28
                                      : 30,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: MyTheme.paddingLeftRightTop(context),
                                      child: ThemeCategoryTab(
                                        listObject: data.listModelOutletTableArea,
                                        onChanged: (var value, int index) {
                                          if (value != null) {
                                            var index = data.listModelOutletTableArea.indexOf(value);
                                            data.onTapFloorSelection(index);
                                          }
                                        },
                                        currentValue: data.listModelOutletTableArea.isNotEmpty ? data.listModelOutletTableArea[data.indexFloor] : null,
                                        text: (int index) {
                                          return data.listModelOutletTableArea[index].name;
                                        },
                                        rowLength: 8,
                                        columnLength: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 20,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: MyTheme.padding(context),
                                      child: Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          (data.listModelOutletTableArea.isEmpty)
                                              ? Center(
                                                  child: ThemeTitle(
                                                    HelperTranslate(context).translate.floor_is_empty.capitalize(),
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              : FloorWidget(
                                                  isLoginFromTenderFloorPlan: widget.isLoginFromTenderFloorPlan ?? false,
                                                ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            WidgetRightSideBar()
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                      // move the footer here
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: WidgetBottomFooterBar,
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                  WidgetLeftSideBar(),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Hopefully it can solve your problem

Comment: that is a nicely detailed answer, kudos!